# lock document after sign with itext

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

after signing a pdf, I want to lock the document, so no more signatures can be added,

I'm trying to add the lock like this:

```
        PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
        dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(placeHolder).setHexWriting(true));

        dic2.put(PdfName.LOCK, stamper.getWriter()
                .addToBody(new PdfSigLockDictionary(LockPermissions.NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED)).getIndirectReference());

        pdfAppearance.close(dic2);
```

but  I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key /Lock didn't reserve space in preClose().
```

I can't find a clear example on how to add this lock, what am I doing wrong? I'm using itext 5.

**EDIT 1:**
setting the LOCK lenght in the preclose like this:

```
PdfSigLockDictionary dic3 = new PdfSigLockDictionary(LockPermissions.NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);

HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<PdfName, Integer>();

exc.put(PdfName.LOCK, dic3.length()* 2 + 2);

pdfAppearance.preClose(exc);
```

I get no error, buy i see no changes in my pdf:
[image: no lock i guess...]

Comment: Please look at the JavaDocs of `PdfSignatureAppearance.close` - it says that the argument  *is a `PdfDictionary` that must have exactly the same keys as the ones provided in `preClose`*. Apparently you did not provide that argument during `preClose`. That being said, it does not make sense to set the **Lock** dictionary at that place. The **Lock** dictionary belongs into the signature field dictionary, not the signature dictionary.

Comment: @mkl I tried to add the key in the preclose like edit 1, but I still see no lock :(

Comment: As I said at the end of the other comment, _the Lock dictionary belongs into the signature field dictionary, not the signature dictionary_. You try to put it into the signature dictionary which is wrong.

Comment: @mkl i do not see that method or variable, could you elaborate?

Comment: Please show your signing code. The few code lines you already do show seem to indicate that you are not using the iText 5 high level signing API but instead in some way employ the low level signing options.